# Facebook og:image won't center

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I have a transparent .png which I have expanded the canvas to 1500x785 to achieve the 1.91 to 1 ratio Facebook says to use. My image is centered. Yet the thumbnail facebook generates is pushed to the right... not centered. The image is all there but just not centered. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

When I actually do share... it makes a square... and doesn't even show the beginning and end of the text...

Here is the image I want

http://delawaretennisacademy.com/assets/Delaware-Tennis-Academy-Logo-Facebook.png

Here is how Facebook says it will be displayed

[image]

Comment: Have you tried adding a white background to your image?

Comment: After many hours fussing with it... I ended up using a .jpg. With a white background. The png just would not work even after many many many different sizes, configs, etc etc. Not ideal because the .jpg is not quite as crisp!